# SQL Server HA-DR for mirroring , How to recover mirroring when...?

Tags: sql, sql-server, high-availability, database-mirroring

what is the fastest way to recover databases mirroring after the primary server shut down and 
the mode of the primary db is in recovery padding or  in mode not synchronize?

Answer (score 2):

If the primary is `In Recovery`, you cannot simply restart mirroring, i.e. you'll have to use backups to recreate it and then re-establish mirroring.

If it's `Suspended`, as is usually the case if you lose the primary, start using the mirror, and then bring the primary up again, then you only need to resume:

```
alter database [your_db] set partner resume
```

Comment: And if the mirror was not synchroneous you will loose the data that was still in the transfer queue - which is exactly as it should be as you set it up like that. Just as a word of reminder.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that deactivate mirroring and then active your mirroring again:

by following query you can deactivate mirroring:

```
Alter Database YourDatabase Set Partner = off
```